# Django: output video file associated with a specific user

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have customuser model name Profile and VideoFile models with relative fields to User. There are many users account and each of them can add a lot of video files. I need to show at templates.html user.nickname and all of him videofiles.

**user.models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, verbose_name="Никнэйм")        
    userpic = models.ImageField(upload_to='userpics/', blank=True, null=True)
```

**videofile.models.py**

```
class VideoFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="vstories/%Y/%m/%d", validators=[validate_file_extension])
    date_upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False, blank=True, null = True)
    descriptions =  models.TextField(max_length=200)
    reports = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vstories = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank = True, null = True)
```

**views.py**

```
def vstories (request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()        
    return render(request, "vstories/vstories.html", {'profiles':profiles})
```

**templates.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% if users %}
{% for user in users %}

<p>{{ user.profile.nickname}}</p>

{% for vstorie in vstories %}
<p>{{ vstorie.vstories.url }}</p>
{%  endfor %}

{%  endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

With the video, I'm confused. Or maybe I chose the wrong way to communicate models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the foreign keys "backward". In this case, to access to all videos of a user (Profile), you need to have all Profiles:

```
def vstories (request):
    profiles = Profile.objects.all() 
    return render(request, "vstories/vstories.html",{'profiles':profiles})
```

Then, in the template, you can access the relationship between Profile and VideoFile "backward".

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
    {% for videofile in profile.videofile_set.all %}
        <p>{{ videofile.file.url }}</p>
    {%  endfor %}
{%  endfor %}
```

The trick is in the "_set" that allows you to follow the relationship backward.

Here is the documentation for this kind of queryset:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Hm, I try but nothing appears. video files were added by the user

Comment: In <p>{{ videofile.vstories.url }}</p> I replaced **vstories** to **file** and now I see only link to my videofile

Answer (score 1):

This work for me

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
    {{ profile.nickname }}

    {% for videofile in profile.videofile_set.all %}
        <video width="320" height="240" controls src="{{ videofile.file.url }}">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    {%  endfor %}

{%  endfor %}
```